# Can you have a gerund and an infinitive in the same sentence?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

1.) **It's better to have one of our allies close to us than having none at all.**

2.) **Having one of our allies close to us is better than having none.**

Comment: Your question should not be whether you can have a gerund and an infinitive in the same sentence (obviously you can: *Having a gerund an an infinitive in the same sentence is a common thing to see*) but whether they work in parallel. As may be seen from your example, they don't.

Comment: Sounds OK, but I doubt if it is in fact correct.

Comment: Is it better to ask than being ignorant? Or is it better not knowing than to ask?

Comment: It's purely a matter of style. Personally, I don't think there's anything really jarring (and certainly not wrong) about either of your examples: neither is _incorrect_, as such. But having two infinitives or two gerunds paralleling each other would be more elegant. You're quite likely to hear examples with mixed usage a lot in common speech, but if you're aiming for style and elegance in writing, I'd advise avoiding them—especially because they're so easy to avoid.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a matter of "correctness"—your sentence with the mixed constructions is technically "correct"—but of effectiveness.

Your job as a writer is to make it as easy as possible for the reader to grasp your meaning. When you are contrasting two propositions you want to make clear exactly what the difference is between them. One very powerful means of effecting this is employing parallel constructions. Your second version does this:

> ```
>                Having *one* of our allies close to us 
> is better than having *none*.
> ```

Similarly, you might recast the first version with parallel constructions:

> ```
>  It is better to have *one*         of our allies close to us
>          than to have *none* at all.
> ```

In both, placing *one* and *none* in the same context allows the reader to apprehend the contrast between them in the very rhythm and sequence of words.<sup>†</sup> Placing them in different contexts, as your 'mixed' construction does, obscures the contrast. It makes the reader work harder than necessary to understand what you're saying, which is discourteous, and it raises the risk that the reader will misunderstand, or just give up, which is ineffective.

---

<sup>†</sup> To my mind your rewrite is also superior to the original in dropping the empty "at all", which I suspect is only there because the contrast in the original is so feeble.

Comment: How about the second example?

Comment: @Jamie Edited to address that.

Comment: +1 for your answer to the OP’s question, Stony. However, I must take exception to your blanket assessment that a writers job is to “*make it as easy as possible for the reader to grasp your meaning.*” While that advice is always accurate for technical writing and journalism, it is not always true for creative writing, where, were it followed, would reduce our literature to a series of recycled clichés. While I am also not advocating the converse, I often enjoy a writer who challenges my skills as a reader.

Comment: @LittleEva I'll stick with the characterization: as easy as possible *but no easier*. Innovation comes about because the poet seeks to express a meaning that lies beyond the established linguistic conventions: her task is to extend the language to encompass new meaning and prevent her readers from evading the meaning she intends.

Answer (score 1):

One can have both gerund and infinitive in the same sentence. But the moot question is whether they work in parallels; and obviously they don't. Consider these sentences the first one of which is akin to your example.

•It is better to have loved and lost than to have never loved at all.

••To see is to believe.

•••Seeing is believing.

They make perfect combinations.

Comment: How about this: Having one of our allies close to us is better than having none.

Comment: @Jamie: *Having one ally is better than having none* is idiomatically fine, but in your case arguably the relatively long "object clause" *one of our allies close to us* puts too much distance between the two elements *(one/none)* being "paralleled, contrasted". Personally, I end up stumbling slightly over the parsing (I find myself drawn to assuming it's better than having ***no allies at all***, rather than having *one of your [multiple] allies **close to you***).

Comment: @Barid: The actual Shakespeare quote for your first example has ***never*** immediately after ***than***. I can't say for sure whether it's simply familiarity with the original colouring my judgement, but your version doesn't seem quite so "elegant" to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Shax' version reinforces the verbal parallelism with metrical parallelism: *better to have loved and* -- *never to have loved at*

Comment: @StoneyB: Ah! It's so obvious once you explicitly point out *why* the version we know and love is a "better" sequence! I wouldn't mind betting that even if Shakespeare had been having an off day when he originally penned it, at least one of the surviving folios would have featured the "improvement", so that would be still be the one we know today anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Something felt wrong about that when I was writing it ... it's not in fact Shakespeare at all, it's Tennyson, from *In Memoriam*.